# How to get the name from a path (file/directory/drive/UNC path)

Tags: c#, path

Example:

```
folder\file.txt -> file.txt (relative path)
C:\folder -> folder (directory)
C:\folder\ -> folder (directory with trailing separator)
D:\ -> D (drive)
\servername\sharename -> sharename (UNC path)
```

I need a **generic method** that handles the above paths and returns a string, thanks!

Comment: The `Path` class has a lot of methods. Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I temporarily use `Path.GetFileName(Path.TrimEndingDirectorySeparator(Path.GetFullPath(path)))`, but I think this is not the best solution, and it can't handle drives or UNC path.

Comment: What do you want back if the input is a single slash, or a period?

Comment: Root directory and current directory.

Answer (score 0):

While `Path` has good helper methods for getting Folder and File names, you seem to be after whatever is the last *fragment* of a string with slashes in it.

```
private static string GetLastFragmentFromPath(string path)
{
    var lastFragment = path.Split('\\', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[^1];

    return lastFragment[^1] is ':'
        ? lastFragment[0..1]
        : lastFragment;
}
```

This satisfies all the cases in your post.

- `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` makes sure that if your input ends with a slash then it's ignored.
- `[^1]` means "last".
- The ternary operator is only needed because you want the drive letter, without the colon.

Limitations

- Use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` in `Split` if you need cross-platform support.
- `\`, which isn't a valid Windows path (but `/` is a valid Linux/MacOS path), will throw an exception.
- A `.` will return itself.
- In Windows, a file or folder cannot contain a `:`, but in Linux (and maybe MacOS) it can. If you expect to parse those OS's paths you will need to account for it.

I'm sure there are other ways to break this. Use this as the basis for your solution, and do more testing to ensure it's robust for your use cases.